# Are there two unequal decimal numbers where the integer part is the same and the decimal expansion is reversed such that there sum is an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

Given a decimal number $d$ we define the function $D$ to be the number where the integer part is the same and the decimal string is reversed.
For example, $D(5.879)=5.978$, $D(-800.5924)=-800.4295$ and $D(7.2)=7.2$.
If $a\neq b$ and $D(a)=b$ then can $a+b$ be an integer?

Comment: If you allow infinite decimal expansions, $(k+\frac{1}{11})+(k+\frac{10}{11})=2k+1$ works (sort of).

Comment: @KeithBackman I don't feel like it makes any sense to talk about reversing infinite decimal expansions. Why should the reversal of $\frac{1}{11}$ be $\frac{10}{11}$ and not $\frac{1}{11}$, or if we get technical why shouldn't it be any random string of digits. (Of course if we pretend it makes sense this is the best answer you could get)

Comment: @Fishbane I agree with you. That's why I put the disqualifier 'sort of' in the comment (not an answer!). To be an answer, we would have to agree on the dubious proposition that $0.090909\dots$ is the digit reversal of $0.909090\dots$ which presupposes an identity for the digit in the 'infinite' decimal place, or else just arbitrarily decree those two to be digit reversals without some independent basis. Only if we make that arbitrary decree does it work (sort of).

Comment: @Fishbane BTW you can play this trick with other fractions such as $\frac{18}{99}=0.181818\dots$ and $\frac{81}{99}=0.818181\dots$

Comment: @KeithBackman Yeah I agree, I just though it was worth making it clear. Your comment did actually make me think about the idea of considering the limit of reversing longer initial segments, but it turns out that even that doesn't work for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that some $a$ exists satisfying the requirements. First notice that $a$ must have a finite decimal expansion as otherwise $D$ is not defined. If the decimal part is zero clearly $a=D(a)$ which is a contradiction.

If the decimal part is non-zero then it is clear that the final non-zero digit added to the first digit must equal exactly $10$. If the decimal expansion is exactly $1$ digit long it must be $5$ and so $a=D(a)$ which is a contradiction.

Now consider that if the decimal expansion is greater than $1$ digit long the first digit added to the last digit equals $10$ and so if there is any carry into the first decimal place when doing $a+b$ we would immediately have a contradiciton as the total for the first decimal place would not be zero.

However if the second decimal place recieved any carry it would have to carry forward again to be able to end up at zero, therefore the second decimal place cannot recieve any carry.

Repeating this procedure we eventually reach the second to last decimal place, but we know that this place recieved carry from the last decimal place which is a contradiction.

The only way around this is if the first decimal place is the last decimal place, but we already showed that was a contradiction.

Therefore by contradiction no number $a$ meeting the requirements can exist.